# How to track nested object in a MobX store

Tags: javascript, mobx, mobx-react

Let's stay I have this myObject loaded via an API call:

```
myObject = {
  fieldA: { details: 'OK', message: 'HELLO' },
  fieldB: { details: 'NOT_OK', message: 'ERROR' },
}
```

Only details and message of each field can change. I want this object to be observable in a MobX store (which properties? to be defined below). I have a simple React component which reads the two fields from the store:

```
@observer
class App extends Component {
  store = new Store();

  componentWillMount() {
    this.store.load();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.store.fieldA && <p>{this.store.fieldA.details}</p>}
        {this.store.fieldB && <p>{this.store.fieldB.details}</p>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I read [this page](https://mobx.js.org/best/react.html) trying to understand what MobX reacts to, but still didn't get a clear idea. Specifically, which of the 4 stores below would work, and why?

1/

```
class Store1 = {
  @observable myObject = {};

  @action setMyObject = object => {
    this.myObject = object;
  }

  load = () => someAsyncStuff().then(this.setMyObject);
}
```

2/

```
class Store2 = {
  @observable myObject = {};

  @action setMyObject = object => {
    this.myObject.fieldA = object.fieldA;
    this.myObject.fieldB = object.fieldB;
  }

  load = () => someAsyncStuff().then(this.setMyObject);
}
```

3/

```
class Store3 = {
  @observable myObject = { fieldA: {}, fieldB: {} };

  @action setMyObject = object => {
    this.myObject = object;
  }

  load = () => someAsyncStuff().then(this.setMyObject);
}
```

4/

```
class Store4 = {
  @observable myObject = { fieldA: {}, fieldB: {} };

  @action setMyObject = object => {
    this.myObject.fieldA = object.fieldA;
    this.myObject.fieldB = object.fieldB;
  }

  load = () => someAsyncStuff().then(this.setMyObject);
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All of the above will work, except for solution 2.
That because as described in Mobx docs about objects:

> When passing objects through observable, only the properties that
>   exist at the time of making the object observable will be observable.
>   Properties that are added to the object at a later time won't become
>   observable, unless `extendObservable` is used.

In the first solution you re-assign the object again with the properties already exist in the returned object.
In 3 and 4 you initialized the object with those 2 properties so it works.

Also I think in your component example you meant to use it like this (otherwise, it won't work in any way):

```
render() {
    const { myObject } = this.store;

    return (
      <div>
        {myObject && myObject.fieldA && <p>{myObject.fieldA.details}</p>}
        {myObject && myObject.fieldB && <p>{myObject.fieldB.details}</p>}
      </div>
    );
}
```